# VSCode EMMET will not complete Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, emmet

So I'm using vscode and before I was able to type `div.col-4` for example and it would auto complete like emmet likes to do `<div class="col-4"></div>`

Currently when I try to do this it will not auto complete any col I try (unless it's a col by itself)

It works normally for other classes but I can't get it to work for columns

[image: screenshot of dropdown menu]

It gives me options like it wants to work but once I pick a column it stops
[image: dropdown menu is gone]

Hitting tab or enter after this it just adds whitespace.

I saw other questions giving the suggestion to turn on the expansion on tab setting but that is already on.